# Finiteness of the sum of the product of an i.i.d. sequence

Tags: self-learning, time-series, law-of-large-numbers

Before I go to the statement of my question I just want to say a few words about 
the *personal* background of this question. I have recently taken a course on stochastic differential equations without prior exposure to the cornerstones of this subject such as measure theoretic probability, real analysis and so on. In contrast with my expectations at the beginning of the course I got one of the highest grades in a class filled with math majors at graduate level. One way or the other I have to say heartfelt thanks to saz and Did and this seems like a place as good as any. There is no way I could have gotten this far in this subject without their help. I felt like this had to be acknowledged somehow. Anyhow, with the knowledge and the confidence I got from this course I decided to study a rigorous treatment of time series on my own. To my surprise and also disappointment to a certain extent, this undertaking is not the smooth sailing I expected it to be. So here is my question.

Let $(Z_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be an i.i.d sequence with $E[\log(Z_t^2)] < 0 $ for each $t \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}Z_t^2Z_{t-1}^2\cdots Z_{t-j}^2 < \infty \quad \text{ almost surely}$$
There is also a hint that I should consider the law of large numbers.

My previous attempt was based on the monotone convergence theorem, which was proved wrong with a counterexample given by d.k.o. So I have erased that attempt.

Comment: You need other assumption on $Z^2$. Example: $P\{Z^2=e\}=P\{Z^2=e^{-2}\}=0.5$ s.t. $EZ^2>1$ and $E\log Z^2=-0.5$

Comment: By the way which law of large numbers do you use?

Comment: @d.k.o. ok so your example clearly devoids my approach. thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes. You need to assume $EZ^2\le 1$

Comment: @d.k.o. well the question doesn't state it. i assumed it would be the strong one. the weak one would require the use of something like Borel-Cantelli, which I think is going overboard given that this is one of the first questions of the first chapter of the lecture notes I am following. But I am just speculating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem wants you to use the (strong) law of large numbers (LLN) on the individual terms.  Recall by the LLN and the definition of convergence to a limit "with probability 1" that: If $\{W_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a general sequence of i.i.d. random variables and $E[W]$ is finite, then (with prob 1) for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find a positive integer $M_{\epsilon}$ such that: 
$$ \left|E[W]-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n W_i\right| \leq \epsilon \: \: \: \: \forall n \geq M_{\epsilon} $$
You can apply this to the $Z_t \cdots Z_{t-j}$ product. In this case, $t$ never changes, so you can define $W_0=\log(Z_t^2), W_1=\log(Z_{t-1}^2), W_2=\log(Z_{t-2}^2)$, and so on.
Then you can fix a sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$ (how small should it be?) and compute bounds on: 
$$ term_j \equiv \prod_{i=0}^j Z_{t-i}^2 = e^{\frac{j+1}{j+1} \log\prod_{i=0}^jZ_{t-i}^2}  = e^{(j+1)\left[\frac{1}{j+1}\sum_{i=0}^jW_i \right]}$$

Then argue that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} term_j < \infty$ (with prob 1).

Comment: "Then argue that ..." statement in your last line.. How do you argue that exactly?

Comment: Well, it follows if the terms $term_j$ are eventually all sufficiently small.

Comment: $E[\log(Z_t^2)] < 0$, so choose any $0 < \epsilon < |E[\log(Z_t^2)]|$; then invoke LLN: with probability $1$ there exists $J$ such that $\frac{1}{j+1} \sum_{t=0}^j W_t < E[\log(Z_t^2)] + \epsilon < 0$ for $j \geq J$. Then $\sum_{j=0}^{J-1} term_j$ is finite since it's a sum of finitely many finite terms, and $\sum_{j=J}^\infty e^{(j+1) \left[ \frac{1}{j+1} \sum_{t=0}^j W_t \right]} \leq \sum_{j=J}^\infty e^{(j+1)( E[\log(Z_t^2)] + \epsilon)}$ which is a convergent geometric series, since $E[\log(Z_t^2)] + \epsilon < 0$.